# XCMPallet send transact: error WeightNotComputable

Tags: xcm, xcmp

I get the WeightNotComputable error when I try to send this XCM transaction. What am I doing wrong?

In [the documentation I've read](https://paritytech.github.io/polkadot/xcm/v2/prelude/opaque/enum.XcmError.html#variant.WeightNotComputable):

```
WeightNotComputable
The weight of an XCM message is not computable ahead of execution.
```

I know the XCM pallet can't know the required weight beforehand...but I don't understand why I get this error ?

**PS**: To create the XCM transaction call in a script I've done this:

```
    const destination = {
        X1: {
            Parachain: parachainId.toNumber(),
        }
    };

    let templatePallet_hex_call = await parachainApi.tx.templatePallet.doSomething(22).signAsync(account);
    console.log("templatePallet_hex_call", inspect(templatePallet_hex_call.toHex(), false, null, true))

    const message = {
        Transact: { originType: "Native", requireWeightAtMost: 10000000000, call: compactAddLength(hexToU8a(templatePallet_hex_call.toHex())) }
    }
    
    console.log("destination", inspect(destination, false, null, true))
    console.log("message", inspect(message, false, null, true))

    const txHash = await relaychainApiInst.tx.xcmPallet.send(destination, message).signAndSend(account);
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: have same issue sending ROC from Rococ to Rocmine https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Frococo-rpc.polkadot.io#/extrinsics/decode/0x630201000100a10f01000101002aa47c41b763a16946b6cc7e051174877b14fafe5d8daf075b0e39e2398c8e4c0104000000000700e876481700000000

Comment: @DzmitryLahoda see answer bellow, maybe it'll help.

Answer (score 1):

Its been a while, but I think I solved it using this code bellow.

Note the `.method.toU8a()` to get the call.

```js
const destination = {
    V0: {
        X1: {
            Parachain: parachainId.toNumber(),
        }
    }
};

let templatePalletcall = await parachainApiInstInsurance.tx.templatePallet.doXcmMessage(account.address, "Hello world").method.toU8a()


const message = {
    V0: {
        Transact: {
            originType: "Native",
            requireWeightAtMost: 100000,
            call: {
                encoded: compactAddLength(templatePalletcall)
            }
        }
    }
}

const txHash = await relaychainApiInst.tx.xcmPallet.send(destination, message).signAndSend(account);

console.log("txHash: ", txHash.toHex())
```